# Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse throws exception unexpectedly

Tags: google-drive-api

We are using PHP client: **"google/apiclient": "1.0.4-beta"** to upload a CSV to our google drive.  Our script was working before, but stop working now. We haven't change anything. We tried dev, staging, production Google Product ID, all throw same error.  Is there any problem on API side ?  or there is some problem on our script ?

Exception :

```
#0 /home/dev/workspace/fb/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(44): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#1 /home/dev/workspace/fb/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(499): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#2 /home/dev/workspace/fb/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(195): Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#3 /home/dev/workspace/fb/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Drive.php(1694): Google_Service_Resource->call('insert', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
#4 /home/dev/workspace/fb/app/modules/Core/Models/Report/Generator/Spreadsheet/Google.php(53): Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource->insert(Object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile), Array)
#5 /home/dev/workspace/fb/app/modules/Core/Models/Report/Manager.php(69): Core\Models\Report\Generator\Spreadsheet\Google->insert('report_21_test_...', Array)
#6 /home/dev/workspace/fb/app/modules/Core/Commands/Report/GenerateByQuery.php(55): 
......
```

Our Code:
        $client = new \Google_Client();

```
    $client->setClientId($apiConfig['clientId']);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials(new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $apiConfig['accountName'],
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'),
        $key
    ));

    $this->service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);


    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    // slice to max rows
    $data = array_slice($data, 0, self::MAX_ROWS);

    // generate spreadsheet with filename and data
    $file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle("$filename");
    $file->setDescription("Report generate at $date");
    $file->setMimeType(self::MIME_TYPE_ORIGINAL);

    $csvStr = $this->getCsvString($data);

    $createdFile = $this->service->files->insert($file, array(
        'data'       => $csvStr,
        'mimeType'   => self::MIME_TYPE_GOOGLE,
        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
        'convert'    => true,
    )); // exception is from here

    // set permission
    $this->service->permissions->insert($createdFile->getId(), $this->getPermission());
```

Comment: Do you have any more details on the error - either an error message in the exception or a dump of the raw response.

Comment: Also, which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Sounds the Drive API being recovered now without any code change on our side.  Cannot reproduce the error again.

PHP Version:    PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u8

PHP Client:       https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/1.0.4-beta

Answer (score 0):

This was a temporary problem and it is now fixed.